Using two UARTs to receive causes one UART to save data from another
I am working with the STM32-H7 microcontroller and am attempting to receive bytes from another microcontroller and then printing to Putty using the USB UART. I am using USART 2 and 6 with interrupts for receiving and USART3 for sending to Putty.
The weird thing is that I can receive both fine separately, but the USART6 data ends up being overridden by USART2 data. Originally I figured it could just be a typo, but simply removing the line that saves USART2 data allows me to print USART 6 data fine, while including it prints USART2 data (encoder_r_data[rx2_indx++] = rx2_data[0];) fine but causes USART6 to also print out USART2 data.
I have already checked it numerous times myself and with another colleague so we have ruled out typos. Sorry about the messy code, I'm just trying to get this to work as a proof of concept and will clean it up later. Thanks for the help in advance.
uint8_t rx2_data[1];  // Single byte to hold received data
uint8_t rx6_data[1];
volatile uint8_t encoder_r_data[8];
volatile uint8_t rx2_indx = 0;
volatile uint8_t sonar_r_data[2];
volatile uint8_t rx6_indx = 0;
uint16_t sonar[1];
uint16_t frequency[4];
char text2[20];            // Buffer for formatted output
char text6[31];
int pulsePWM1 = 107;
int pulsePWM2 = 107;
int pulsePWM3 = 107;
int pulsePWM4 = 107;
 
while (1)
{
        frequency[0] = encoder_r_data[0] << 8 | encoder_r_data[1];
        frequency[1] = encoder_r_data[2] << 8 | encoder_r_data[3];
        frequency[2] = encoder_r_data[4] << 8 | encoder_r_data[5];
        frequency[3] = encoder_r_data[6] << 8 | encoder_r_data[7];
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        {
          sprintf(text2, "Frequency%d is %u Hz\r\n", i+1, frequency[i]); // Use %u to ensure unsigned conversion
          HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t*)text2, strlen(text2), HAL_MAX_DELAY); // Transmit via USART
        }
        sonar[0] = sonar_r_data[0] << 8 | sonar_r_data[1];
        sprintf(text6, "Distance from sonar%d is %u cm\r\n", 1, sonar[0]);
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t*)text6, strlen(text6), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

        HAL_Delay(1000);
}

        sonar[0] = sonar_r_data[1] << 8 | sonar_r_data[0];
        sprintf(text, "Distance from sonar%d is %u cm\r\n", 1, sonar[0]);
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t*)text, strlen(text), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

        HAL_Delay(1000);
}

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if(huart -> Instance == USART2)
    {
              encoder_r_data[rx2_indx++] = rx2_data[0]; // watch the index stays in scope
              HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, rx2_data, 1); // Arm again
    }

    if (huart->Instance == USART6) // Check if we're handling USART6
    {
              sonar_r_data[rx6_indx++] = rx6_data[0];
              HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart6, rx6_data, 1);
    }
}


Have you confirmed whether your indices are causing your buffer to overflow?

Buffer text2[] is much too short.

Where do you ever reset rx2_indx and rx6_indx? How does the main loop know or check, that received data is available?

@Colin I didn't consider that the indices as a problem since they work fine when reading a single UART. I don't understand overflow that much, so how does the overflow cause rx6_data to be rx2 _data?

After a few interrupts your code is going to start to write to encoder_r_data[8], encoder_r_data[9], encoder_r_data[10], ... etc, the result of which is that it's going to be writing into whatever variables are located after encoder_r_data in memory. It's likely (but not guaranteed) that those other variables which get overwritten are whatever is declared after encoder_r_data in your code - so rx2_indx, sonar_r_data, etc.

@brhans so i tried using simple if statements inside the interrupts to reset the indices but that seems to corrupt the data. What would the best way to reset the indices?

if (rx2_indx > 7) rx2_indx = 0;. Similarly if (rx6_indx > 1) rx6_indx = 0;.
